# mongodb is reachable through each server but replica sets cannot find each other after iptables

Tags: iptables, replication, ping, mongodb

I have 9 machines where I set up mongod replset instances. I set iptables so servers can see each other and i can confirm this sshing into one server and connecting to a mongod in another server. But rp.status command reports that the instances cannot ping each other and also all my servers are nicely pingable using ping utility.

Comment: Are these 9 servers a single replica set or a sharded cluster? Can you include more details such as the `iptables` rules, specific version of MongoDB, and the error message or output of `rs.status()`? Are the hostnames used in your `rs.conf()` resolvable from each replica set member?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
So since docker uses forward table it's useless to use INPUT table, therefore, using FORWARD table directly causes a weird situation like in this very post.
So after a lot of duckduckgoing, i found that actually, all I need to do is to add my rules into docker table